# WP Query tax_query not returning posts

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, tax-query

I have a WP query that searches for any custom posts under type 'tribe_events' tagged as 'featured' under the taxonomy 'tribe_events_cat'.

So, just to be clear:
post_type = 'tribe_events'
taxonomy = 'tribe_events_cat'
terms = 'featured', 'streamteam'

However, it returns nothing when outside of page ID 199. I can comment-out the tax_query and it works but returns all posts, not just ones tagged as 'featured'.

```
  if(is_page(199)) {
    $tribe_events_cat = array( 'featured','streamteam' );
  } else {
    $tribe_events_cat = 'featured';
  }

  // The Query
  $event_args = array (
    'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'tax_query' => array (
      array (
        'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms'     => $tribe_events_cat,
      ),
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => '_EventStartDate',
        'value' => date("Y-m-d"),
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'DATE',
      ),
    ),
    'meta_key'          => '_EventStartDate',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
  );
  $event_query = new WP_Query( $event_args );

  // The Loop
  if ( $event_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $event_query->have_posts() ) {
    $event_query->the_post();
    ?>
    POST CONTENT HERE
    <?php
    }
  }
```

What's wrong with my tax_query?!

**EDIT:**

This answer solved my initial problem of no posts being returned from my query
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30213495/wp-query-returns-no-results 
Apparently there was a filter conflicting with my query.
However, I'm still having an issue.. I only want to return posts with both 'featured' AND 'streamteam' terms when on page ID 199. Right now it's returning posts that only belong to the 'featured' term.

Comment: In the intro, you wrote `taxonomy = 'tribe_events-cat'`, in the query it is `tribe_events_cat`, is that just a typo?

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your help! Here's what I ended up going with:

```
if(is_page(199)) {
  // The Query
  $event_args = array (
    'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'tax_query' => array (
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array (
        'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'streamteam',
      ),
      array (
        'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'featured',
      ),
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => '_EventStartDate',
        'value' => date("Y-m-d"),
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'DATE',
      ),
    ),
    'meta_key' => '_EventStartDate',
    'order' => 'ASC'
  );
  } else {
    // The Query
    $event_args = array (
      'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'suppress_filters' => true,
      'tax_query' => array (
        array (
          'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => 'featured',
        ),
      ),
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => '_EventStartDate',
          'value' => date("Y-m-d"),
          'compare' => '>=',
          'type' => 'DATE',
        ),
      ),
      'meta_key' => '_EventStartDate',
      'order' => 'ASC'
    );
  }
$event_query = new WP_Query( $event_args );

// The Loop
if ( $event_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $event_query->have_posts() ) {
  $event_query->the_post();
  ?>
  POST CONTENT HERE
  <?php
  }
}
```

Instead of using an array (`$tribe_events_cat`) for my `terms` subquery, I had to use two single-term `terms` subqueries, turning my `tax_query` into an AND request for posts in `featured` AND `streamteam`.

Also, I had to add `'suppress_filters' => true,` to each args array to fix some weird filtering issues happening outside of my query that were affecting my results.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've just tested this in my installation (with a taxonomy that exists here). Usually, I just quickly throw stuff into the functions.php and look at the SQL that's generated (`print $event_query->request;`). That didn't work and the tax_query always generated `0 = 1` thus making sure that there were no results.

Finally, heureka, the taxonomy wasn't registered at that stage. Running it later and it works as expected.

Might something similar happen for you? Is your taxonomy-registration-code maybe working differently based on what page is currently requested?

In any case, please also add the SQL that is generated to the question. That might shine some light. How is your taxonomy added, CPTUI or similar, or your own code?

Maybe throw in

```
foreach ( get_post_types() as $post_type ) {
   echo '<p>' . $post_type . ": " . var_export(get_object_taxonomies($post_type), true) . '</p>';
}
```

Just to be sure.

Comment: From running `foreach ( get_post_types() as $post_type )... ` just above my `$event_args = array` declaration I get: 'tribe_events: array ( 0 => 'post_tag', 1 => 'tribe_events_cat', )', which means that the taxonomy `tribe_events_cat` is registered at the time of the wp_query call, right?

Comment: Yeah, that looks fine. Have you looked at the SQL (and manually ran it against the database)?

Comment: Yes, ran against the database and it returned post id 312, which is a post that only belongs to 'featured' and NOT 'streamteam'. Is there a chance my tax_query is pulling in posts from 'streamteam' OR 'featured'? I could have sworn that passing an array into a single 'terms' parameter in the tax_query meant automatically using an AND operator?

Comment: Yeah, an array will basically be translated to `IN(val1, val2)`. You'll have to use two single-term-subqueries, if you want an AND.

Answer (score 0):

You used this `'meta_key' => '_EventStartDate',` for which purpose? Everything looks fine, did you try commenting the `meta_query`

Comment: Yeah, I tried commenting out the `meta_query`, no luck. Still pulling in posts that belong to `streamteam` OR `featured`. I want it to only pull posts that belong to both `streamteam` AND `featured` when on page ID 199. `'meta_key' => '_EventStartDate'` is ordering the posts by `'_EventStartDate'`, which are being pulled in by my `meta_query`. The `meta_query` is pulling in posts that have an `'_EventStartDate'` that occurs in the future.